# Recursive Haskell function seemingly doesn't terminate

Tags: haskell, recursion

To improve my Haskell skills, I'm trying to solve the [Advent of Code 2018](https://adventofcode.com/). As expected, I am already stuck on day 1, specifically on part 2:

> --- Part Two ---
>
> You notice that the device repeats the same frequency change list over
>   and over.
>
> To calibrate the device, you need to find the first frequency it
>   reaches twice.
>
> For example, using the same list of changes above, the device would
>   loop as follows:
>
> Current frequency  0, change of +1; resulting frequency  1.
>
> Current frequency  1, change of -2; resulting frequency -1.
>
> Current frequency -1, change of +3; resulting frequency  2.
>
> Current frequency  2, change of +1; resulting frequency  3.
>
> (At this point, the device continues from the start of the list.)
>
> Current frequency  3, change of +1; resulting frequency  4.
>
> Current frequency  4, change of -2; resulting frequency  2, which has
>   already been seen.
>
> In this example, the first frequency reached twice is `2`. Note that
>   your device might need to repeat its list of frequency changes many
>   times before a duplicate frequency is found, and that duplicates might
>   be found while in the middle of processing the list.
>
> Here are other examples:
>
> +1, -1 first reaches 0 twice.
>
> +3, +3, +4, -2, -4 first reaches 10 twice.
>
> -6, +3, +8, +5, -6 first reaches 5 twice.
>
> +7, +7, -2, -7, -4 first reaches 14 twice.
>
> What is the first frequency your device reaches twice?

Basically, I have a very large list `vals::[Int]` that includes all the frequency changes mentioned above.

Here is the function I wrote for solving this problem:

```
-- [1] The list of frequency changes
-- [2] The first repeat frequency
--             [1]      [2]
part2helper :: [Int] -> Int
part2helper ds = go ds []
    where go ds [] = go ds [0]
          go (d:ds) [f] = go ds $ (f+d):[f]
          go (d:ds) (f:fs) =
              if f `elem` fs then f
              else go ds $ (d+f):f:fs
```

I test this function with the values provided in the description in `ghci`:

```
*Main> part2helper (cycle [1, -2, 3, 1])
2
*Main> part2helper (cycle [1, -1])
0
*Main> part2helper (cycle [3, 3, 4, -2, -4])
10
*Main> part2helper (cycle [7, 7, -2, -7, -4])
14
*Main>
```

All result are correct, so I assume my function works correctly. The problem now is, when I compile this into a program that reads the input list from a file, the program never terminates. Here's the code:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

main = do 
    [input] <- getArgs
    s       <- readFile input
    let n    = lines $ s
        vals = map (read::String->Int) $ fmap (filter (/='+')) n
        sol  = part2helper (cycle vals)
    print sol

-- [1] The list of frequency changes
-- [2] The first repeat frequency
--             [1]      [2]
part2helper :: [Int] -> Int
part2helper ds = go ds []
    where go ds     []     = go ds [0]
          go (d:ds) [f]    = go ds $ (f+d):[f]
          go (d:ds) (f:fs) =
              if f `elem` fs then f
              else go ds $ (d+f):f:fs
```

This builds with GHC correctly, but as I said, never terminates and prints no result. What am I missing? The input file can be found [here](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/1/input).

Comment: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm

Comment: It is possible that no frequency is ever reached twice. For example `[11,-1]` will just go off to infinity.  You might want to `Debug.Trace` in `part2helper` to see if this is happening, or if it's a performance thing as `melpomene` suggests (though your algorithm could be improved, I have my doubts that it's a performance problem)

Comment: The function `go` is partial. `go [] [] == undefined`

Comment: Actually it might be.  I thought a solution would always be found within 2 cycles, but I was mistaken--it might take up to n cycles, which would make your algorithm O(n^4). That could easily get slow.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, but it's only ever given an infinite list.

Comment: @luqui is correct; I was working on my laptop, I just ran it on my desktop, and it produces the correct result after some time. So it is simply a very ineffective algorithm that runs criminally slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to put everything together in a single function. It's much better if you work in a modular fashion, breaking the problem into smaller ones.

Here's an idea,

- generate the sequence of frequencies,
  `f0, f1, f2...`
- generate the sequence of cumulative sets of frequencies
  `{}, {f0}, {f0,f1}, {f0,f1,f2}...`
- check repeated insertions, i.e.
  `fi` such that `fi ∈ {f0..fi-1}`

To make things clearer regarding the last point consider,

```
 f0, f1,   f2,      f3...
 {}, {f0}, {f0,f1}, {f0,f1,f2}...`
```

if `f3` were a repetition then `f3 ∈ {f0,f1,f2}`

This may seem terribly inefficient but because Haskell is lazy, these lists will be generated as needed.

We'll need to import modules to work with sets and maybes,

```
import Data.Set
import Data.Maybe
```

Generating the frequencies from the first frequency and a list of frequency changes can be done via `scanl (+)`. The function `scanl (+) x xs` operates the elements of `xs` with the operator `+` , starting at `x`, generating the cumulative list of sums.

```
freqs :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
freqs = scanl (+)
```

Now we can generate the list of sets. Here too we use a `scanl`. In each step we insert a new frequency, and we start with the empty set.

```
sets  :: [Int] -> [Set Int]
sets  = scanl (\s x -> insert x s) (empty)
```

Once we have the frequencies and the sets we are pretty much done.The main function just puts everything together. It combines both lists and finds the first pair `(fi , {f0,...,fi-1})` such that `fi ∈ {f0,...,fi-1}`, and returns the corresponding `fi`

```
result :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
result x xs = let fs = freqs x xs
                  ss = sets fs                  
                  r  = find (\(y,s) -> y `elem` s) (zip fs ss)
              in fmap fst r
```

Note `find` returns a `Maybe (Int, Set Int)`. It may find `Nothing` or return `Just (x,s)` for some frequency `x` that was already in `s`. We use `fmap fst` to turn `Just (x,s)` into `Just x`.

---

**EDIT**

Once you've got things working if you wish to, may optimize a few things, or play around with your style. The following is a more succinct, and possibly a little bit more efficient version.

The list of frequencies and sets can be built together in one go.

```
freqsets :: Int -> [Int] -> [(Int, Set Int)]
freqsets f0 = scanl (\(f,s) x -> (f+x,insert f s)) (f0,empty)
```

And so it's ready to use for the result function. Also we can take advantage of `Maybe` being a monad to make things a bit more readable.

```
result :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
result f0 xs = do (f,_) <- find(\(y,s)->y `elem` s) (freqsets f0 xs)
                  return f
```

And there you have it, a rather short solution. I like the change in the result function. I like the `do` notation, as well as not having it calculate the zipping of the two previous lists. I'm not so sure if "fusing" the building of both lists is worth it. It's a bit less readable. Using three functions, one for frequencies, one for sets, and one for zipping, might be best.

Comment: Very thorough answer and analysis! I was thinking along these lines a bit, but went for "slow and dirty". But such math analysis are almost the most fun about such stuff.

Comment: @georgjz Added a shortened version by the way. Also note that while it is indeed fun, it's also a matter of  practicality. It makes it easier to understand, to reason about, to test, to adapt, etc. Even if you optimise things latter, it's good to have a simple and easy to read version around, that you can use to test the correctness of  your changes.