# Check if a list of lists has two or more identical elements

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I need to write a function which checks if a list has two or more same elements and  returns true or false.

For example `[3,3,6,1]` should return true, but `[3,8]` should return false.

Here is my code:

```
identical :: [Int] -> Bool
identical x = (\n-> filter (>= 2) n )( group x )
```

I know this is bad, and it does not work.
I wanted to group the list into list of lists, and if the length of a list is >= 2, then it is should return with true otherwise false.

Comment: Two or more *consecutive* equal elements? Or can the identical elements be placed anywhere?

Comment: The second, it does not matter if it is consecutive or not.

Comment: Hint: what is `n` here? A list `[Int]`? or a length `Int`? Given you filter this, what will the result be?

Comment: Maybe a length Int? I tried to `[n]` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `any` to get a Bool result.

```
any ( . . . ) ( group x )
```

Don’t forget to sort the list, `group` works on consecutive elements.

```
any ( . . . ) ( group ( sort x ) )
```

You can use (not . null . tail) for a predicate, as one of the options.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand what does `not . null . tail` do.

Comment: `null` returns True if a list is empty, we check if the list still has elements after the first one. The equivalent would be  `(\x -> (tail x) /= [])`

Comment: I would probably have gone for `(not . null . drop 1)` because `drop 1` is total unlike `tail`. however due to the semantics of `group` (it never produces empty lists), it doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: This is a neat readable and simple way to go about it. It's good to keep in mind though requiring the list to be sorted is rather inefficient. This could be a  simple linear algorithm and it could work even in infinite lists (not the case with sorting). To make things worst, some sorting algorithms only let you access elements once the list is fully sorted, which is the case with merge sort which GHC implements.

Comment: I find `not . null . tail` not very clear. Might be worth defining a function `longerThan :: Int -> [a] -> Bool`, then it becomes very clear: `any (longerThan 1) . group . sort`.

Comment: @JorgeAdriano Sorting is no less efficient than repeated `Set` insertions (which are O(lg n), not O(1), using the `Set` type from the `containers` library, anyway).

Comment: @chepner True, you're right. Still, the point holds that one doesn't have to sort the whole list beforehand to find a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Just yesterday I posted a similar algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53772617/1442575). A possible way to go about it is,

- generate the sequence of cumulative sets of elements
  `{}, {x0}, {x0,x1}, {x0,x1,x2} ...`
- pair the original sequence of elements with the cumulative sets
  `x0, x1  , x2     , x3         ...`
  `{}, {x0}, {x0,x1}, {x0,x1,x2} ...`
- check repeated insertions, i.e.
  `xi` such that `xi ∈ {x0..xi-1}`

This can be implemented for instance, via the functions below. 
First we use `scanl` to iteratively add the elements of the list to a set, producing the cumulative sequence of these iterations.

```
sets  :: [Int] -> [Set Int]
sets  = scanl (\s x -> insert x s) empty
```

Then we zip the original list with this sequence, so each `xi` is paired with `{x0...xi-1}`.

```
elsets :: [Int] -> [(Int, Set Int)] 
elsets xs  = zip xs (sets xs)
```

Finally we use `find` to search for an element that is "about to be inserted" in a set which already contains it. The function find returns the pair element / set, and we pattern match to keep only the element, and return it.

```
result ::  [Int] -> Maybe Int
result xs = do (x,_) <- find(\(y,s)->y `elem` s) (elsets xs)
               return x
```

Answer (score 1):

The another way to do that using `Data.Map` as below is not efficient than `..group . sort..` solution, it is still `O(n log n)` but able to work with infinite list.

```
import Data.Map.Lazy as Map (empty, lookup, insert)

identical :: [Int] -> Bool
identical = loop Map.empty
    where loop _ []     = False
          loop m (x:xs) = if Map.lookup x m == Nothing
                          then loop (insert x 0 m) xs
                          else True
```

Answer (score 0):

OK basically this is one of the rare cases where you really need `sort` for efficiency. In fact `Data.List.Unique` package has a [`repeated`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Unique-0.4.7.5/docs/Data-List-Unique.html#v:repeated) function just for this job and if the source is checked one can see that `sort` and `group` strategy is chosen. I guess this is not the most efficient algorithm. I will come to how we can make `sort` even more efficient but for the time being let's enjoy a little since this is a nice question.

So we have the `tails :: [a] -> [[a]]` functions in `Data.List` package. Accordingly;

```
*Main> tails [3,3,6,1]
[[3,3,6,1],[3,6,1],[6,1],[1],[]]
```

As you may quickly notice we can `zipWith` the `tail` of `tails` list which is `[[3,6,1],[6,1],[1],[]`], with the given original list by applying a function to check if `all` item are different. This function could be a list comprehension or simply the `all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool` function. The thing is, I would like to short circuit `zipWith` so that once i meet the first dupe let's just stop `zipWith` doing wasteful work by checking the rest. For this purpose i can use the monadic version of `zipWith`, namely `zipWithM :: Applicative m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m [c]` which lives in `Control.Monad` package. The reason being, from it's type signature we understand that it shall stop calculating any further when it accounts for a `Nothing` or `Left whatever` in the middle if my monad happens to be `Maybe` or `Either`.

Oh..! In Haskell I also love to use the `bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a` function instead of `if` and `then`. `bool` is the ternary operation of Haskell which goes like

```
bool "work time" "coffee break" isCoffeeTime
```

The negative choice is on the left and the positive one is on the right where `isCoffeeTime :: Bool` is a function to return `True` if it is coffee time. Very composable as well.. so cool..!

So since we now have all the background knowledge we may proceed with the code

```
import Control.Monad (zipWithM)
import Data.List (tails)
import Data.Bool (bool)

anyDupe :: Eq a => [a] -> Either a [a]
anyDupe xs = zipWithM f xs ts
             where ts = tail $ tails xs
                   f  = \x t -> bool (Left x) (Right x) $ all (x /=) t

*Main> anyDupe [1,2,3,4,5]
Right [1,2,3,4,5] -- no dupes so we get the `Right` with the original list
*Main> anyDupe [3,3,6,1]
Left 3 -- here we have the first duplicate since zipWithM short circuits.
*Main> anyDupe $ 10^7:[1..10^7]
Left 10000000 -- wow zipWithM worked and returned reasonably fast.
```

But again.. as i said, this is still a naive approach because theoretically we are doing `n(n+1)/2` operations. Yes `zipWithM` cuts redundancy down greatly if the first met dupe is close to the head but still this algorithm is O(n^2).

I believe it would be best to use the heavenly `sort` algorithm of Haskell (which is not merge sort as we know it by the way) in this particular case.

Now the algorithm award goes to -> *drum roll here* -> `sort` and `fold` -> *applause*. Sorry no grouping.

So now... once again we will use a monadic trick to utilize short circuits. We will use `foldM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b`. This, when used with `Either` monad also allows us to return a more meaningful result. OK lets do it. Any `Left n` means `n` is the first dupe and no more calculations while any `Right _` means there are no dupes.

```
import Control.Monad (foldM)
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Bool (bool)

anyDupe' :: (Eq a, Ord a, Enum a) => [a] -> Either a a
anyDupe' xs = foldM f i $ sort xs
              where i = succ $ head xs -- prevent the initial value to be equal with the value at the head
                    f = \b a -> bool (Left a) (Right a) (a /= b)

*Main> anyDupe' [1,2,3,4,5]
Right 5
*Main> anyDupe' [3,3,6,1]
Left 3
*Main> anyDupe' $ 1:[10^7,(10^7-1)..1]
Left 1
(2.97 secs, 1,040,110,448 bytes)
*Main> anyDupe $ 1:[10^7,(10^7-1)..1]
Left 1
(2.94 secs, 1,440,112,888 bytes)
*Main> anyDupe' $ [1..10^7]++[10^7]
Left 10000000
(5.71 secs, 3,600,116,808 bytes)   -- winner by far
*Main> anyDupe $ [1..10^7]++[10^7] -- don't try at home, it's waste of energy
```

In real world scenarios `anyDupe'` should always be the winner.